# How to plot on queried data of influxdb?

Tags: python, pandas, plot, data-analysis, influxdb-python

I am using Influx DataFrameClient in python to retrive data:

```
from influxdb import DataFrameClient

cli = DataFrameClient(host='localhost',port =   8086,database='rahul')

q= cli.query('select * from cpu')
print(q)
```

But the query retrieves data in `dict` format with a lot of improper header shift (which surprised me):

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {u'cpu':                                         host    region  value
2018-05-26 10:14:03.151530998+00:00  serverA   us_west   0.64
2018-05-26 10:20:08.584895220+00:00  serverB   us_east   0.74
2018-05-26 10:21:53.594648689+00:00  serverC  us_north   0.84
2018-05-26 10:22:03.750544189+00:00  serverC  us_south   0.91
2018-05-26 10:22:22.360371835+00:00  serverA  us_north   0.10
2018-05-26 10:30:19.126093956+00:00  serverB   us_east   0.19
2018-05-26 10:30:36.509174972+00:00  serverA  us_north   0.21
2018-05-26 10:30:52.672447701+00:00  serverB   us_west   0.81})
```

I tried doing `pandas.DataFrame(q)` to transform the queried data to dataFrame but didn't work.

So, here how can I plot say `date` versus `value` data and what if manipulations needed on data, how to apply `pandas` for manipulations ??

Is there any way to transform these queried data to dataFrame using pandas and hence manipulate to visualize it ?

Answer (score 0):

The DataFrameClient returns a Dictionary of DataFrames with the measurement names as keys.

If you use `q["cpu"]` that should give you your Dataframe with correct header and you can do with it whatever you want.